# Neo4j from PHP, check if a node exist, if not create it

Tags: neo4j

I'm accessing neo4j through PHP. I'm new to this and would like to know the best way to solve a simple case.

I need to check if an specific node already exists (based in an auto_index comparison), if it does, set some properties, and if it doesn't exist, thus create it with some properties.

Please consider that I'm using Cypher queries throughPHP.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Cypher for this: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create-unique.html#create-unique-create-node-if-missing
 or use Composer (the preferred method.)
Cypher queries can be executed over the REST interface (which you must use if accessing from PHP.) Documentation here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-send-queries-with-parameters

Quick plug: I'm the author of Neo4jPHP, which handles Cypher queries, among other things. You can use Composer (the preferred method) or get it directly from github (https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp)

Comment: Thanks Josh, The problem that I have is that if I use de crete unique (for sure I'm doing something wrong) the destination node (the one I need to create if missing) it's created several times.  The case is the following, I have the node of a person, then I want to link it to a company one for an employment relationship, before creating the company node I just need to check if it already exists (by some id, like company_id=XX). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the Neo4j documentation under creating unique nodes with cypher. Note that if the node with that particular unique property already exists then it won't be created again. Here's the link http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html

**Get or create unique node (create)**

The node is created if it doesn’t exist in the unique index already.

Example request

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/people?uniqueness=get_or_create
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "key" : "name",
  "value" : "Tobias",
  "properties" : {
  "name" : "Tobias",
  "sequence" : 1
 }
}
```